# How to only crop objects from images after finding the edges of objects in php?

Tags: php, gd, imagick

My basic query is first how to find edges of an object in the image and then crop out the whole object from the picture?

I have figured how to find edges of an object via gd and Imagick, can't figure out how to crop out only the object which got edges.

Lastly here is my workflow

1. Take an image
2. Do crop based on entropy
3. Find object/edged content in image
4. Crop that object out save as an image.

below is code what i use after cropping the image by a php library autocrop , the library crop the image to most important part what i need after that i use below code

```
$f='girle.jpg';
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($f);    
imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH, 10);
imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_EDGEDETECT
```

adding a sample image

[this is the image i get after crop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ABib.jpg)
[this is image with edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bwn4.png)

i want to extract/crop only the image at edges like cutting an image out of a magazine around the edge like a scissor.

Comment: How far have you gotten? Where are you stuck? [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As a newcomer to Stack Overflow, also take the [tour].

Comment: If you've got that far, http://phpimagick.com/Tutorial/backgroundMasking would probably get you the rest of the way.